# Ajax with bootstrap.TbSelect2 (Yii)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have a Select whose contents are changed when another Select is changed.
On change ajax runs a function in my controller to do this:

```
$this->renderPartial("_townsselect", array('country'=>$country));
```

It gets $country from a $_GET.

**_townselect.php**

```
$towns= $this->townsselect($country);
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2', array(
    'name'=>'clienttown',
    'asDropDownList' => true,
    'data'  => $towns
));
```

townsselect() creates an array structured as: $towns[*town-id*]='*TownName*'

When the page is loaded normally it also runs the previous renderPartial with $country set manually as a default.

So it is calling the same code both times.  However on page load the Tbselect2 is shown correctly (correct styling, includes js support which gives it a search box, etc...), but when I use ajax a standard Select is used with limited styling.  In fact the code produced is different:

**Result after page load**

```
<div class="select2-container" id="s2id_clienttown" style="width: 220px">
    <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">  
        <span>Accrington</span>
        <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close" style="display:none;"></abbr>
        <div>
            <b></b>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="select2-drop select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active select2-offscreen" style="display: block;">
        <div class="select2-search">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="select2-input" tabindex="-1">
        </div>
        <ul class="select2-results"></ul>
    </div>    
</div>
  <select name="clienttown" id="clienttown" style="display: none;">
      <option value="Select">Select</option>
  ...
  </select>
</div>
```

Where as after the ajax only the Select is generated.

**Temporary Solution**

I managed to get this working in some form.  Instead of recreating the whole select box I have altered the JQuery code to clear all options inside the Select and refill it with the new list.
The new list comes comes from a JSON string returned by the ajax.  Which is processed as follows:

```
var towns = $.parseJSON(resp);
$('#clienttown option:gt(0)').remove(); //remove all options, but leave default 'Select A Town' option
var sel = $('#clienttown');
$.each(towns, function(id, town){
    sel.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", id).text(town));
});
```

I've put this here in case it helps someone else trying to achieve a similar thing.

Howver I would still be interested to know why yiibooster/bootstrap does not work when rendered after ajax.  And if there is a way to make it work, as this solution wont work unless the input is first rendered on page load.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but have you tried the following to get the after Ajax rendering to work.

```
// Notice the ,false, true at the end of renderpartial
$this->renderPartial("_townsselect", array('country'=>$country), false, true);
```

Comment: Hi, just noticed your comment. Now on a new project and found my own question on google haha.  For the last project I stuck with the solution I came up with.  I've since tried the solution you mentioned but it caused script clashes and broke the theme.  My solution doesnt work on this new project though as I'm trying to load the whole select via ajax